# Remove holoviews heatmap colors

Tags: python, holoviews

I am new to pyviz, and I am looking at holoviews for interactive plotting.

I am trying to remove the heatmap (hv.HeatMap) colors, something like `color='white'`, or `color=None`.

Does anyone know how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the fill_alpha=1 and line_alpha=1, e.g.:

```
hv.HeatMap(((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3))).opts(fill_alpha=0, line_alpha=1)
```

[image]

Comment: That really helped. Thanks a lot!